# How to define a starting rule in ANTLR?

Tags: python, antlr

I want to execute the example from the [ANTLR python target](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md) page, but I have no idea, how to define the `startRule()`-Function to enter the code to a specific rule.
Could somebody give an example to a `startRule()`-Definition?

Answer (score 5):

The startRule() function is just a parser rule in your grammar. Let's say your grammar, kept in a file called `MyGrammar.g4`, looks like this:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

// A parser rule that matches zero or more ANY_CHAR tokens 
// followed by the EOF (end-of-file)
startRule
 : ANY_CHAR* EOF
 ;

// A lexer rule that matches a single character
ANY_CHAR
 : .
 ;
```

then you could call `startRule()` on the generated parser.

Answer (score 1):

The ANTLR parser doesn't really have the concept of a start rule - you may choose any rule as your start rule when invoking it (by calling the appropriate method, e.g. `start()` if you want to start at the rule `start`).

This can be useful if you need to start at different rules for different use-cases.

It might still be a good idea to call your start rule something like `startRule` in your grammar for readability, but it's not mandatory.